# Laravel - How to pass model to the view without querying database when working with remote API to get Data?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, model-binding, rest

I'm working on a Laravel web project that is fully integrated with external/remote Rest API. I'm trying to pass a model object that returned from API to a GET route by implicitly route binding but the default behavior that Laravel did is trying to reference this model object from the database while no database connection defined in my application.

Comment: Can you please share [the code you already have](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [customize the resolution logic](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-resolution-logic):

```
class ApiModel
{
    /**
    * Retrieve the model for a bound value.
    *
    * @param  mixed  $value
    * @param  string|null  $field
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null)
    {
        return Http::get('api/path/for/model')->json();
    }
}
```

If you need to further modify the model class to have an eloquent-like model, you can use or borrow from [`jenssegers/model`](https://github.com/jenssegers/model).

Comment: Thanks @shaedrich for your contribution, but what if the remote API doesn't contain API to get a single model object? Only I can get the model object from a List!

Comment: Maybe you tell me/us a little more about your API then.

Comment: I have only one API to get a products list and I'm listing those products on the index page. Now I need to make a details page for each product that I already loaded from the API

Comment: You either call the API to get all products and filter the returned array (not recommended) or you have to save the result in your session or a JSON file.